Accessing private aws ec2 instances for external monitoring tools
What are the possible ways to access the aws ec2 instances which are in private subnets for monitoring purposes.
I have an external monitoring tool (CheckMK). I want to connect it to private ec2 instances to gather metrics about ec2 instances and applications running on these instances.

Amazon EC2 instances in private subnets are, by definition, not accessible from the Internet.
You might be able to launch another EC2 instance in a public subnet and use it as a 'jump box' for the external service. See if that service has a 'jump box' or 'bastion server' capability. This will let it connect to the instance in the public subnet and then forward traffic to the instance in the private subnet.

What are your views about aws ec2 instance connect endpoint.
This connects to private instances without requiring them to have public IP address.

Oh! I didn't know that existed! Looks like it was added in June 2023. It allows you to connect to an instance via the VPC Endpoint. However, it doesn't seem to support Port Forwarding, so this isn't an option. You could, however, use Port Forwarding Using AWS System Manager Session Manager | AWS News Blog. This uses an Agent on your instance to 'call out' to the AWS Systems Manager service and it supports port forwarding that might let your monitoring tool reach the instance.

There is another option that I am thinking is to shift the ec2 instances from private to public subnet and control the access through security groups inbound rules that only allow traffic from monitoring service. How secure is this option?

Yes, this is perfectly acceptable. The concept of public/private subnets is actually a hold-over from the old world where network security was applied at subnet boundaries. The cloud, however, adds security on every resource. Therefore, a security group can provide plenty of security if configured correctly. You would be able to open access to desired IP address ranges.
